# Java RegExp escape repeated single quote

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string by single quotes, but taking into account that a repeated single quote represents a escaped quote. So for example the following string

```
String ss ="aaa''bbb'ccc''ddd'eee";
```

would be splitted in

```
aaa''bbb
ccc''ddd
eee
```

so the regular expression should be something like "Any single quote that is not preceded by a single quote and its not followed by a single quoted". The expression to avoid the single quote not followed by a single quote is simple:

```
String regexp= "'(?!')";
```

But I was unable to apply the condition "not preceded by a single quote". Any ideas?

TIA

JL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are u looking for this?

```
"(?<!')'(?!')"
```

Comment: yep, needs both negative look ahead and negative look behind.

Comment: where is @Raze2dust 's answer?? I just added a comment, and his answer is gone. Can one delete his own answer? here I can only see "vote to remove", what does this do? really remove or just send the request?

Comment: He removed his answer as I have removed mine (since my answer was the same as yours, and you beat me to the punch).

Comment: could you please tell, how to do the remove? just click the 'vote to remove this post' ? because sometimes I also post the 'same' answers. :( I know that feeling. :)

Comment: @Kent, I removed it. As you said, it would look for blocks of three characters. I was trying to avoid look-ahead, but I guess it is necessary here.